# reccurence relation, particular solution does not work

Tags: probability-theory, recurrence-relations

I have linear nonhomogeneous reccurence equation:

$$pa_n-a_{n=1}+(1-p)a_{n-2}+1=0$$

I solve homogeneous equation first and I get: $a_n=A+B(\frac{1-p}{p})^n$

Now I want to guess particular solution, so I try constant one $K$ because nonhomogeneous term is constant, but

$$pK-K+(1-p)K+1=1$$

Why constant solution does not work? How to solve this reccurence relation?

Comment: Constant solutions do not work when the characteristic polynomial has $1$ as a root.

Answer (score 1):

A constant doesn't work because it is a solution to the *homogeneous* equation. For this specific equation, one can find a particular solution in the form $a_n=Cn$, where $C$ is a constant to be determined:
$$
pCn-C(n-1)+(1-p)C(n-2)+1=0\implies C=\frac{1}{1-2p}.
$$

---

Remark: I have assumed that $p\neq\frac{1}{2}$. If $p=\frac{1}{2}$, even the solution to the homogeneous equation must be modified. The general solution to the recurrence equation, in this case, is
$$
a_n=A+Bn-n^2\qquad\left(p=\frac{1}{2}\right).
$$